# limitar uma tabela SQL a um só registro e não deixar a aplicação c# inserir mais registros nessa tabela

Tags: c#, sql

Boa Tarde

Sou novo nisto de c# e SQL mas fiz um aplicação  em c# e tenho um tabela Empresa que quero limitar a um só registro ( uma empresa única) e pretendo que o utilizador posso alterar ou apagar esse registro mas não consiga inserir mais nenhum.
O código que fiz em c#

```
private bool IfidExists(string EmprId)
        {

            con.dataGet("Declare @EmprId INT,SELECT @EmprId= COUNT(*) FROM Empresa IF@EmprId>'1'BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; RETURN;END ");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con.sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
  if (Validation())

 if (IfidExists(txtEmprId.Text))
                 {
                    MessageBox.Show("Só pode Registrar uma empresa");
```

mas não me deixa registrar nenhum empresa

Agradeço desde já a vossa ajuda

Comment: O que, em seu modelo, define que a empresa é duplicada? use campo para criar uma chave única. E não escreva suas queries dessa forma, é melhor utilizar o `SqlCommand`

Comment: não seria só fazer um `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Empresa`? para fazer um simples select não precisa de `transaction`

Comment: Qual BD ?  Cria a tabela , insere um registro e cria uma trigger de before insert or delete dando erro na execução , uma forma simples.

Comment: Bom dia Motta  string de ligação já esta no formulário a tabela Empresa está criada, a coluna EmprId que é chave primária e autoincrement, podes por favor dar me um exemplo do trigger?

Comment: por "limitar uma tabela SQL a um só registro" entendo que a tabela só terá um registro é ponto final , para que diacho uma chave autoincremento ?!  supondo MySql este post faz algo parecido com o que quer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24/throw-an-error-preventing-a-table-update-in-a-mysql-trigger

Answer (score -3):

Acho que estás a fazer várias coisas mal... Transações é só para escrita (insert/update) e leituras é redondante...

Podes fazer um select genérico, e fazes o if de existencia depois, e não necessitas do declare, nem count que é mais lento!

Comment: Bom dia Carlos agradeço desde já pela ajuda mas neste caso o que pretendo é que  query verifique se o campo EmprId que é chave primária e autoincrement é maior que 1 e se sim so deixe fazer update e delete. obrigado